# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 call to web api targeting .net framework does not get called

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a solution with contains a class library targeting the .Net framework 4.7 and another project with ASP.NET Core 2.2 .

The class library targeting the .Net framework contains controllers as shown below with the route prefix and the route name

[image]

And then in my StartUp.cs i have configured the below 
[image]

On running this i make a call to the api in the .Net framework class library the call does not return the response from the web api instead returns the default index.html content.

[image]
What am i missing in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see on the first screen classes like `RoutePrefix`, `ApiController`, `HttpResponseMessage`. They are from classic `Asp.Net WebApi`. It is impossible to use old ApiControllers in `Asp.Net Core`. It means you need to rewrite you controllers using `Asp.net Core`.

Asp.net core projects may targeting to both `.net core` and classic `.Net Framework`. If you really need to target to the `.Net Framework` you can create a class library targeting the .Net framework 4.7, create there `Asp.Net Core` controllers and then use that library in `Asp.Net Core` project as an external dll.

Comment: I tried with creating a class library with 4.7 framework but when i add reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App i get via nuget i get error "Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author"

Comment: you need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in your route. The correct way to mark a route param as optional is with a `?`:

```
[Route("List/{cKey?}"]
```

The default, should be on the action param:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string cKey = null)
```

Then, you can request just `List` and it will hit this action and `cKey` will be null, because it wasn't supplied. As you have it now, the `cKey` param is required, so you can only reach this route via `List/foo`, where "foo" is your `cKey` value.